# use SQL script to create SQL server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a very basic question about SQL server and Visual Studio 2010. I'm currently reading the book "C# 3.0 Unleashed with the .NET framework 3.5". I'm at the chapter where LINQ to SQL is explained. The writer asks to create a new database and use his script (given in the book) to create the tables and fill these with some data.

However, as I've never worked with SQL server before, this part is a bit confusing for me. The writer doesn't explain how to create the database. First I thought I could just right-click on `Data Connections -> Create New SQL Server Database`. However, when I tried that, I only got an error explaining no connection could be made.

When that didn't work, I added a new `Service-based Database` via `Add -> New Item`. This works (although I do not understand the difference between this and the previous thing I've tried. If someone could explain this for me, It'd be very appreciated), but now I'm supposed to use the script to create the tables and enter some data. I can right-click on the database and select `New Query`, but that window doesn't seem to accept such scripts.

First part of the script:

```
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[HospitalStaff]Script Date: 12/29/2007 21:42:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N’[HospitalStaff]’)
AND type in (N’U’))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [HospitalStaff](
[HospitalStaffID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Position] [varchar](50)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_HospitalStaff] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[HospitalStaffID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
END
```

I know it's a very basic question, but where can I execute this script? I've visited several websites with SQL server tutorials, but it's all pretty confusing.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Visual Studio 2010:" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add a new .sql file in your solution with .sql extension
- Open that file
- Right click
- Execute script

[image]

more info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yea4bc1b(vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that, I have to connect to the database engine which doesn't work as I'm getting the same error as the one I got when trying to create the new database.

Comment: This error: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg138/scaled.php?server=138&filename=errorbi.png&res=medium

Comment: I get the insufficient memory exception message

Answer (score 2):

You may use a program to access it.

For instance SQL Server Management Studio is an integrated environment for accessing, configuring, managing, administering, and developing all components of SQL Server.

Check more info [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a database name in the Object Explorer in SSMS, go to Tasks -> Generate Scripts for all objects.  Save it to a new query window, and you can see the text necessary for creating a new database from scratch and populating it with objects (tables, SPs, etc.)

Use this code to help you figure out how to generate a create string.

Example:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [DBA]    Script Date: 02/07/2012 11:40:09 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [DBA] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'DBA', FILENAME = N'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\DBA.mdf' , SIZE = 1303552KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'DBA_log', FILENAME = N'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\DBA_log.ldf' , SIZE = 2052672KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an eloquent solution

Problem
Database in Asp.NET web Visual Studio 2010 when running on PC with SQL Server 2008 Express
I can use the interface to manually add tables but I wanted to run SQL code to create tables etc.
You can't do this from the query interface (*highlight database and from popup choose "New Query")*

The idea stated above of using a script seemed like the way to go – but when I went to do that I couldn’t figure out how to connect to my database that was in the solution.

If I choose “Connection…” and the SQL Server Express 2008 that was running on my PC it would default to “master” and when I tried to browse to the database using [Options] it wasn’t in the list.
It also went to “master” when I explicitly put the full path in 
C:\Users\keef.riffhard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\MyAspDatabase.mdf

AGGGG!!

The trick was also in [Options] is “Additional Connection Parameters” with a note “Connection string parameters override graphical selections in other panels”
So I highlighted the database in my solution and then went to properties and copied the connection string.
I then pasted the connection string into the |Additional Connection Parameters| tab under [Options]

SUCCESS !!

Comment: please just post what works, most of us don't need/want to know everything you did to find it out.